# welcome baby party vs baby shower party

Tags: word-usage

could you please tell me what the difference between baby shower and welcome baby party is? And is there a party that American families throw after the baby get born?

Comment: Yes, it's called their "first birthday party" because new parents are usually so busy the first year they can't handle parties until they've had a year to recover. :P Generally baby parties are for expectant mothers, not for the exhausted parents of newborns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A baby shower is thrown before the child is born, and I think it's typically thrown by a friend of the expectant mother. A welcome baby party is thrown shortly after the child is born. There's some discussion of the etiquette of the two [here](http://community.babycenter.com/post/a26702585/baby_shower_vs._welcome_baby_party.please_no_rude_comments). The ones supporting welcome baby parties seem to be those where the mother is having a difficult pregnancy, so would not be up for a party during the weeks leading to the due date.